# Java portable media detection

Tags: java, usb-drive

I would like to write a piece of java code that synchronizes files between local hard drive and a usb storage. I would like to have a different synchronization configuration depending on which usb storage is plugged in and I would like to have apropriate configuration to be selected automatically rather than chosen by the user.

I've just read the [JSR-80](http://javax-usb.org/) and [jUSB](http://jusb.sourceforge.net/) documentation as well as a bunch of [articles](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-usb.html) and SO posts, but all of those are very old and it seems that since that time (around 2005) all the efforts have been abandoned especially for Windows platform, while the OS-independence is quite important to me (at least Windows and Linux need to be supported).

Do I really need to use any of the USB APIs to recognize external drives that are connected to the system? I need something that is more unique than file path, drive letter or drive label... And if yes which one would you recommend (unless I missed something jUnit is actually the only for which Windows support exists).

Answer (score 1):

There has been more recent activity than that on the jUSB sourceforge project.  Sure, he/they haven't released a snapshot since 2000-ish, but the last commits were in 2005, and someone was changing project information in August this year.

If you are serious, consider donating some effort to help get the project moving again.